# Insert sed in a one liner to strip a string from the filename

Tags: shell, sed

This should be an easy question. Using the linux terminal I want to crop images in a folder using convert and change their name using sed. For example,
The following one liner crops the images in a folder as i expect:

```
for file in Screenshot*.png; do convert -crop 1925x1060+10+1 $file newname_$file; done
```

However, I want to strip the "Screenshot-" string from the filename. With sed I could use sed -n 's/Screenshot-//p' :

```
echo "Screenshot-1.png" | sed -n 's/Screenshot\-//p'
```

But how can I insert sed in the for loop above?

For example, if I have a folder with these images:

```
Screenshot.png  Screenshot-1.png  Screenshot-2.png  do_not_crop.png
```

I expect to see these files:

```
Screenshot.png  1.png  2.png  do_not_crop.png
```

Additional points for who can tell me how to convert Screenshot.png to 0.png

Edit: based on hek2mgl's answer, this script works:

```
for file in Screen*png; 
do convert -crop 1925x1060+10+1 $file 
    $(if [[ "$file" == "Screenshot.png" ]];
     then echo "0.png";
     else echo "${file#Screenshot-}";
     fi);
done
```

and outputs 0.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use bash's [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) rather than `sed`.

Example:

```
for file in Screenshot.png  Screenshot-1.png  Screenshot-2.png  do_not_crop.png ; do
    echo "${file#Screenshot-}"
done
```

Output:

```
Screenshot.png
1.png
2.png
do_not_crop.png
```